# Reposition UIImages in different patterns iOS (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uiimage

What I want to do is have a UICollectionView with a UIButton in it's cell, and there are about 15 cells (hence 15 UIButtons). This is not a problem for me to achieve. However, if the user clicks on a certain button, several images below the UICollectionView should rearrange/reshuffle/reposition in a certain pattern. So each button in the collectionView essentially creates a different (non-random) pattern of layout of these images.

I haven't really started because I don't know how exactly to begin, so I'm sorry that I can't provide any code. But from the research I've done, making container views seems like a likely option. But the problem is i'll have to create 15 different files & controllers for the 15 different patterns. Is this the only solution or is there another way to go about it? Please let me know if the question is vague or you need more help understanding. Thanks!

Comment: 15 different controllers for 15 patterns of images is definitely the wrong direction. Why not put your images in a collectionView and have the buttons reshuffle the cells in the collection view to whatever order you need. Since the buttons are sitting in a collection view it could also be one collection view with two different sections.

Comment: I can't use a collectionView for the images because the patterns that I want mean they won't be aligned perfectly all the time, with one up or down sometimes. Take a look at this link  - http://www.futwiz.com/en/fifa17/squad-builder . Play with the 'formations' options to see how the cards move around. That's what I would like to replicate! @null

Comment: I still don't think you should make a container view for each formation. That's not a scalable solution what if tomorrow you'll need 30 formations? What you need is a container view that can dynamically change the formation of the images according to the data. That team formation looks like a chart to me, maybe this library can help https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts

Comment: Could you maybe tell me how to use charts with images or buttons? I have been trying to look for tutorials, but the few tutorials that I have found focus on inputting data for line graphs. And there is no documentation for iOS. Thank you for the ideas though!